# Android Adapter doesn't work when selecting multiple cardviews

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, onlongclicklistener

I have a problem, I don't understand why my `CardViews` have this effect.

I need select one or more `CardViews` but my adapter does not work fine.  Is my implementation of the adapter incorrect?

[image]

**My Adapter**

```
public class PersonasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < PersonasAdapter.PersonasViewHolder > {

 private Persona subject;
 private List < Persona > personastList;
 public PersonasAdapter() {}

 public PersonasAdapter(List < Persona > personastList) {
  this.personastList = personastList;
 }


 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonasViewHolder personasViewHolder, int i) {
  Persona ci = personastList.get(i);
  personasViewHolder.txtNombre.setText(ci.getNombre());
  personasViewHolder.txtUsuario.setText(ci.getUsuario());
  personasViewHolder.txtTwitter.setText(ci.getTwitter());
  subject = personastList.get(i);

  personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Eliminar Cardview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
    return false;
   }
  });
  personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Reproducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });
 }
 @Override
 public PersonasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
  View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout_persona, viewGroup, false);
  cardView
  return new PersonasViewHolder(itemView);
 }
```

**Class Static**

```
public static class PersonasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      protected TextView txtNombre;
      protected TextView txtUsuario;
      protected TextView txtTwitter;
      protected CardView card_view;

      public PersonasViewHolder(View v) {
       super(v);
       txtNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
       txtUsuario = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
       txtTwitter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTwitter);
       card_view = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
      }
     }
     //Metodo que nos retornarta la cantidad de personas en la lista
     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
      return personastList.size();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
The problem are the position the cardview.

i declare global variable

```
int globalPosition;
```

and

```
 personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Eliminar Cardview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
            globalPosition=i;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and a validation in

and a if in onBindViewHolder

```
 if (i == globalPosition) {
  personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
 } else {
  personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
 }
```

and the result it's this.

```
public class PersonasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < PersonasAdapter.PersonasViewHolder > {

private Persona subject;
private List < Persona > personastList;
public PersonasAdapter() {}
int globalPosition;

public PersonasAdapter(List < Persona > personastList) {
this.personastList = personastList;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonasViewHolder personasViewHolder, final int i) {
Persona ci = personastList.get(i);
personasViewHolder.txtNombre.setText(ci.getNombre());
personasViewHolder.txtUsuario.setText(ci.getUsuario());
personasViewHolder.txtTwitter.setText(ci.getTwitter());
subject = personastList.get(i);


personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Eliminar Cardview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
globalPosition=i;
notifyDataSetChanged();
return false;
}
});
personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Reproducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});



if(i==globalPosition)
{
//change color like
personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);


}
else
{
personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
}

}
@Override
public PersonasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout_persona, viewGroup, false);

return new PersonasViewHolder(itemView);
}
public static class PersonasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
protected TextView txtNombre;
protected TextView txtUsuario;
protected TextView txtTwitter;
protected CardView card_view;

public PersonasViewHolder(View v) {
super(v);
txtNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
txtUsuario = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
txtTwitter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTwitter);
card_view = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
}
}
//Metodo que nos retornarta la cantidad de personas en la lista
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return personastList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, looks good.  But it's amazing to me that almost every article/blog on RecyclerViews has its focus on creating a list, but none on saving the list. It does no good to create a beautifully crafted/valuable list (say a big list of songs I want to download) and then have the list literally be destroyed if I navigate away from the list with the single press of the back button. Why wouldn't saving state code be a requirement for creating every RecyclerView list just like the other requirements: the adapter, the layoutmanager, onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder and getItemCount?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

- You perfom a Long Click on the first PersonasViewHolder of your list.
- Then, in your onLongClickListener, you change the background color of that holder.
- But that holder is then re-used for later positions in the recycler-view, giving the sensation that the background is being repeated in later elements.

You can fix it by storing the state of each cardview in an array, and then binding the correct color for each position. I modified your code to show this idea:

```
public class PersonasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < PersonasAdapter.PersonasViewHolder > {

 private Persona subject;
 private List < Persona > personastList;
 private boolean[] selectedPersonas;
 public PersonasAdapter() {}

 public PersonasAdapter(List < Persona > personastList) {
  this.personastList = personastList;
  this.selectedPersonas = new boolean[personasList.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < personasList.size(); i++) {
      this.selectedPersonas[i] = false;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonasViewHolder personasViewHolder, final int i) {
  Persona ci = personastList.get(i);
  personasViewHolder.txtNombre.setText(ci.getNombre());
  personasViewHolder.txtUsuario.setText(ci.getUsuario());
  personasViewHolder.txtTwitter.setText(ci.getTwitter());
  subject = personastList.get(i);

  updatePersonaHolderBackground(personaViewHolder, i);

  personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Eliminar Cardview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    selectedPersonas[i] = !selectedPersonas[i];
    updatePersonaHolderBackground(personaViewHolder, i);
    return false;
   }
  });
  personasViewHolder.card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Reproducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });
 }
 @Override
 public PersonasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
  View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout_persona, viewGroup, false);
  cardView
  return new PersonasViewHolder(itemView);
 }

private void updatePersonaHolderBackground(final PersonasViewHolder personasViewHolder, final int i) {
    if (selectedPersonas[i]) {
           personasViewHolder.card_view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
    } else {
          // TODO: change the color of personasViewHolder back to normal using whatever color you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Does it have the same behavior as before ? did you changed the  TODO with the proper color ?